# Excel formula to get exact timestamp in hh:mm:ss

Tags: excel, excel-formula, timestamp

Can you please share the Excel formula to get the exact current timestamp till seconds?

I have used "ctrl+shift+;" but here I am getting 00 as seconds. I want the exact seconds along with hours and minutes

Comment: It's a matter of formatting, but a formula will recalculate the timestamp if anything changes in the workbook, therefore I suggest looking into a VBA solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following formula to get the exact timestamp at the moment you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key:

```
=TEXT(NOW(),"[$-x-systime]h:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

However, if you copy this formula to a new cell and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, the timestamp will be updated. If you want to keep the original timestamp, either manually copy and paste (value only) the timestamp to another cell, or look into a solution using VBA (macro).